# How to find all the combinations of list elements without using itertools?

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for an algorithm that would find all possible combinations of list elements without using itertools.
eg. : for [1,2,3,4,5] it prints [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[2,1].......]

Comment: Why the restriction against itertools? itertools is a negligible dependency and will probably be faster than any pure-Python solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23743696/5763413) using recursion.

```
>>> import copy
>>> def combinations(target,data):
...     for i in range(len(data)):
...         new_target = copy.copy(target)
...         new_data = copy.copy(data)
...         new_target.append(data[i])
...         new_data = data[i+1:]
...         print new_target
...         combinations(new_target,
...                      new_data)
...                      
... 
>>> target = []
>>> data = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> 
>>> combinations(target,data)
['a']
['a', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'd']
['a', 'c']
['a', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'd']
['b']
['b', 'c']
['b', 'c', 'd']
['b', 'd']
['c']
['c', 'd']
['d']
```